# 64- bit Microsoft Excel 2010 Addin loading error

Tags: excel, 64-bit, add-in, excel-2010

I developed a 64-bit Addin.

For testing I added it on a laptop (64-bit machine with 64-Windows7 Enterprise and 64-bit Office 2010) [other than the one i developed the Addin on], its works fines i can call n use its functions. but when i add the same addin on a desktop machine (64-bit machine with 64-Windows7 Enterprise and 64-bit Office 2010), its functions are not available and no error message displayed as well. But when i re-launch Microsoft Excel 2010 a message appears.

Message text : "The file you are trying to open, 'MyAddin.xll', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is in from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"

As per the message text i verified that the location for xll is included in "trusted location". Yet the issue not resolved.

Whats your opnion in this regard,

Thanks & Regards,

**Maverick**.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have compiled it Release and not Debug (if you've done the latter it will only work on machines with the debug versions of included DLLs, which usually means machines with Visual Studio installed).